# Strange invalid or unexpected token error

Tags: javascript

I have following line:

```
document.write('<td><input value="Add to ShopBakset" 
        type="button" onClick="addToBasket(\'' + JSON.stringify(products[i]) + '\')"/></td>');
```

and the following code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="center">
 <h1 align="center">Shop Basket</h2>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>

 <table align="center">
<tr>
    <th align="left">Price</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<script>
for(let i=0;i<products.length;i++){
    for(let key in products[i]){
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td>" + key + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + products[i][key] + "</td>");
        document.write('<td><input value="Add to ShopBakset" 
    type="button" onClick="addToBasket(\'' + JSON.stringify(products[i]) + '\')"/></td>');
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
}
</script> // an error occurs here
    </table> 
    <center>
<a href="html-link.htm"><img src="shopbasket.jpg" title="basket" 
    alt="basket"></a>
    </center>
    </div>
    <p id="change"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

closing script tag line outputs invalid or unexpected token. If I am omitting JSON.stringify there is no bug. I am using sublime text to create my applications. Few days ago I had a problem with this type of error. It was caused by a blank line...

EDIT:
Onto 3 lines:

```
document.write('<td><input value="Add to ShopBakset" type="button"'+ 
                'onClick="addToBasket(\''
                 + JSON.stringify(products[i]) + 
                 '\')"/></td>');
```

Comment: JS strings are not spreading on new lines.

Comment: `document.write` is going to remove all other html tags

Comment: What do you mean in simple words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have multiline strings with `''` or `""`. You should use close the string  by `'`. And add `+` it with new string.

```
document.write('<td><input value="Add to ShopBakset"'+ 
        'type="button" onClick="addToBasket(\'' + JSON.stringify(products[i]) + '\')"/></td>');
```

The better way is to use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
document.write(`<td><input value="Add to ShopBakset"
            type="button" onClick="addToBasket(${JSON.stringify(products[i])}')"/>
            </td>`)
```

Comment: do you think should i split it onto 3 strings??Because still the same error?

Comment: @graluc Yes its due to splitting in on three lines.

Comment: @graluc Every time you split the string into new line. Just code the string at that line and use `+` after it and start a new string from new line.